# error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml, rss

i have problem in my website in this link :-

http://www.3-hail.com/API/news.php

i get this error message :-

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

when i try to connect with this file news.php

```
   <?php

    require_once("config.php");

    $result = mysql_query("select * from newsm WHERE news_id='1' ORDER BY id Desc Limit 30"); 

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $title[] = $row['caption']; 
        $Image[] = $row['ext'];
        $postID[] = $row['id']; 
        $Textnews[] = $row['text']; 
        $containing[] = $row['text']; 
        $post_date[] = $row['date'];
    }

    function sublen($text,$of,$to){ 
    if(strlen($text) > $to){ 
    echo substr($text,$of,$to)." ..."; 
    }else{ 
    echo $text; 
    } 
    }

    $count = count($title); 


    for ( $e = 0; $e <= $count-1; $e += 1) {
    }

    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss version="2.0">

        <channel>

            <title>صحيفة عيون حائل</title>
            <link>http://3-hail.com/</link>
            <description>صحيفة عيون حائل</description>';

    for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count-1; $i += 1) {

    $word = array("&nbsp;","[/CENTER]","[/JUSTIFY]","[CENTER]","[JUSTIFY]","[email]","[/email]","[/url]","[url]","[B]","[/B]","[IMG]","[/IMG]"); 
    $text = $containing[$i]; 
    $replace = ""; 
    $containingNews = str_replace($word,$replace,$text); 

    echo '<item>
               <title>'.$title[$i] = iconv("windows-1256", "UTF-8", $title[$i]).'</title>
               <description>'.$substring = mb_substr($Textnews[$i] = iconv("windows-1256", "UTF-8", $Textnews[$i]),0,100,"utf-8").'...</description>
               <containing>'.$containingNews = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(iconv("windows-1256", "UTF-8", $containingNews))).'</containing>
               <link>http://3-hail.com/news.php?action=show&amp;id=' . $postID[$i] . '</link>
               <enclosure>http://3-hail.com/contents/newsm/' . $postID[$i] . '.' . $Image[$i] . '</enclosure>
               <enclosurem>http://3-hail.com/contents/newsm/' . $postID[$i] . '.' . $Image[$i] . '</enclosurem>
               <bubdate>' . date('H:i d-m-Y', $post_date[$i] ) . '</bubdate>
            </item>';

    }

    echo'</channel>

    </rss>';

    ?>
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand? `<?xml` is the XML declaration. It's not on line 1.

Comment: i can't understand why i got this error all thing is good and working in another server for ex : http://qbaas.org/API/news.php

Comment: So, what's on the line before the XML declaration? Use "View Source" in the browser to see that. Then all you have to do is figure out where that first line came from. That will probably help you figure out why it worked on one server and not the other.

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace preceeding the `<?xml`

Comment: yah you are right there is one line empty in the first view-source:http://www.3-hail.com/API/news.php so how can i remove it ?

Comment: - Check your config.php file for blank lines outside of <? and ?> bracketed sections.       that's it ^ـ^